# HTML served by Rails 7 displays differently in browser than same HTML served statically

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 7, Tailwind CSS and Tailwind UI, @hotwire/turbo and @hotwire/stimulus.

I am using the Slideover component in one of my views (https://tailwindui.com/components/application-ui/overlays/slide-overs).

When I visit a page with this slideover component via the Rails dev server, the slideover component covers the entire page. It's not supposed, as you can see in the link. It is only supposed to cover a small portion of the right-side of the screen.

However, if I copy the HTML generated by Rails and save it into an HTML file, load it up directly by opening it in the browser, the slideover displays properly.

I've been at this for a couple of hours now, thinking it might be something with the cache, but clearing it has no effect.

How is that even possible?

Comment: Maybe it is being overwritten by your CSS. If you inspect element, do you only see tailwind classes or do you also see some other CSS that should not be there?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @VictorLuna. Just to be sure, I loaded up the same page in a Private/Incognito Browser which has no browser plugins running, but to no avail. I even tried using different browsers. It really doesn't make sense that accessing the same HTML via Rails Dev Server vs. Static HTML Export would display differently.

Comment: Have you inspect element in the browser to make sure no other CSS is interfering with tailwind?